# (/bin/bash: python3: command not found) When running python script through system command in Matlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I have a large Matlab project, and due to an issue with xlsread and Mac OS, I have included a Mac switch. If that switch is on, I want Matlab to execute a python script through a system command as such:

```
cmdStr = 'python3 osx_conversion.py'
if osxSwitch == 1
    [status,result] = system(cmdStr);
    if status ~= 0
        error('System could not run Python conversion file')
    end
else
...
```

This returns the result:

```
/bin/bash: python3: command not found
```

Now, if instead I use 'python osx_conversion.py', the error I get is to do with using python 3 syntax, as the command python on my mac calls python 2. 
Any ideas as to what is going on will be really appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, if I run 'python3 osx_conversion.py' through the terminal it runs smoothly

EDIT 2: Result from running

```
echo $PATH
```

in the terminal:

```
    /anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: Well, do you have python3 installed by this name on the mac?

Comment: Yes, edited post accordingly

Comment: run `echo $PATH` in terminal and post the result here

Comment: Thank you! Posted result as an edit to the question

Comment: try to change `cmdStr = 'python3 osx_conversion.py'` to `cmdStr = '/anaconda3/bin/python3 osx_conversion.py'` (firstly, run `/anaconda3/bin/python3 osx_conversion.py` in terminal just to make sure it works)

Comment: Hero! That does it. What is the explanation behind that? And more importantly, how do I make it as smooth as possible for collaborators to be able to use this? Assumedly they'll have to run the echo path command then copy and paste part of that result into cmdStr.
PS: How do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: I've added a complete explanation, just mark it as the answer. Hope it made sense, if you have any more questions, don't hesitate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the command run by Matlab wasn't finding your python 3 interpreter, my guess is that it runs as root user, so the PATH is different than the one in your user.

Basically, what you can do is specify the complete PATH for your desired Python interpreter, in your case, it is `/anaconda3/bin/python3`, but that PATH might be different for another user.

In any case, you can always run `whereis python3` in terminal to find out the complete PATH of the user Python interpreter, and use the complete PATH inside Matlab.

Comment: No, MATLAB is not run as root, that would be dangerous. On MacOS, programs started from Finder (the desktop program) do not receive any environment variables or settings defined in `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Comment: That makes more sense